# AngularJS display multiple values in select menu?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have a select menu using Angular 1.5.11:

```
 <select ng-model="abc.user.state" name="state" ng-options="option.code as option.name for option in abc.brStateSelect.options | orderBy: 'name' track by option.code"
    class="form-control" required></select>
```

which uses json such as

`[{ "id": 11, "name": "Rondônia", "code": "RO" }, { "id": 12, "name": "Acre", "code": "AC" }]`

And the menu correctly displays the "name" props.  However I want to display TWO props:  "name" and "code" such as `Acre - AC` as the menu items.

How can I modify my ng-options to display more than one field as a label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this,

```
<select ng-model="abc.user.state" name="state" ng-options="option.name  as option.name + '-' + option.code  for option in datas | orderBy: 'name' track by option.code"  class="form-control" required></select>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.datas =
  [{ "id": 11, "name": "Rondônia", "code": "RO" }, { "id": 12, "name": "Acre", "code": "AC" }];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <select ng-model="abc.user.state" name="state" ng-options="option.name  as option.name + '-' + option.code  for option in datas | orderBy: 'name' track by option.code"
    class="form-control" required></select>
</body>
</html>
```